Maven doesn't download kafka ErrorHandler class with actual dependency
I am going to learn kafka so I tried to do kafka client application like it is on spring.io . When I run application I got error:
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kafkaService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaService' defined in file [C:\Users\Dell Latitude\OneDrive\Desktop\Java Projects\SpringTest\KafkaClient\target\classes\com\pszerszenowicz\test\spring\service\KafkaService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'replyingTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/pszerszenowicz/test/spring/config/KafkaConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'replyingTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repliesContainer' defined in class path resource [com/pszerszenowicz/test/spring/config/KafkaConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'repliesContainer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler not present
2024-05-05 13:15:28.242  INFO 5048 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-05-05 13:15:28.261  INFO 5048 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-05-05 13:15:28.307 ERROR 5048 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kafkaService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaService' defined in file [C:\Users\Dell Latitude\OneDrive\Desktop\Java Projects\SpringTest\KafkaClient\target\classes\com\pszerszenowicz\test\spring\service\KafkaService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'replyingTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/pszerszenowicz/test/spring/config/KafkaConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'replyingTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repliesContainer' defined in class path resource [com/pszerszenowicz/test/spring/config/KafkaConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'repliesContainer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:408) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at com.pszerszenowicz.test.spring.KafkaClientApplication.main(KafkaClientApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler not present
    


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
    ... 112 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1


My main pom file:
    <groupId>com.pszerszenowicz.test.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringTest</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>RabbitMQClient</module>
        <module>RabbitMQServer</module>
        <module>KafkaClient</module>
    </modules>

    <name>springtest</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.boot.starter.version>3.2.5</spring.boot.starter.version>
        <spring.boot.maven.plugin.verion>3.2.5</spring.boot.maven.plugin.verion>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.17</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.maven.plugin.verion}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>

My application module pom file:
    <parent>
        <artifactId>SpringTest</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.pszerszenowicz.test.spring</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>KafkaClient</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

my kafka config class:
package com.pszerszenowicz.test.spring.config;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.TopicBuilder;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    private static final String kafkaRequest = "kafka-request-topic";

    private static final String kafkaReply = "kafka-reply-topic";

    @Bean
    public NewTopic kRequests() {
        return TopicBuilder.name(kafkaRequest)
                .partitions(3)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic kReplies() {
        return TopicBuilder.name(kafkaReply)
                .partitions(3)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer =
                containerFactory.createContainer(kafkaReply);
        repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("repliesGroup");
        repliesContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
        return repliesContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyingTemplate(
            ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer) {
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, repliesContainer);
    }

}


my kafka service class:
package com.pszerszenowicz.test.spring.service;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Header;
import org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.RequestReplyFuture;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class KafkaService {

    ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyingTemplate;

    public String sendAndReceive(String message) {
        replyingTemplate.setReplyErrorChecker(record -> {
            Header error = record.headers().lastHeader("serverSentAnError");
            if (error != null) {
                log.info("Server sent an error: {}", new String(error.value()));
            }
            return null;
        });

        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("", message);
        RequestReplyFuture<String, String,String> future = replyingTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
        String returnString = "error";
        try {
            future.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            returnString = consumerRecord.value();
            log.info("Received return message: {}", returnString);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.info("InterruptedException: {}", e.getMessage());
        }catch ( ExecutionException e) {
            log.info("ExecutionException: {}", e.getMessage());
        }catch (TimeoutException e) {
            log.info("TimeoutException: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return returnString;
    }
}


My controller class:
public class KafkaController {

    @Autowired
    KafkaService kafkaService;

    @GetMapping("/send")
    public ResponseEntity<?> send(@RequestParam String message) {
        String reponse = kafkaService.sendAndReceive(message);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(reponse);
    }

}

As I understand the problem is in initializing bean from kafka ErrorHandler class which is not present but should be downloaded from existing dependency. I tried to remove .m2\repository\org\springframework\kafka folder and download it again by maven but it didn't work.
Can you tell me what can I do to solve it and what the problem is if I don't uderstand it correctly?

I solved it, It was spring compatibillity problem with newest kafka dependency. I updated spring dependency to newest and everything is fine.
